# Apply patch to specific Mercurial code version?

Tags: mercurial, patch

I got a patch for software managed in Mercurial (in the form of a .diff file). The author of the patch said it is "based on [some UID]".

How do I get the version of the code corresponding to this UID? I tried to apply the patch to the latest code in the repository, using `hg import filename.diff`, and got "chunk failed" errors.

<s>I also tried `hg clone -r [UID]` and got an "invalid arguments" error.</s> I also tried `hg clone -r [repository] [UID]` and got an "abort: unknown revision" error.

(FWIW I asked the patch author and the software mailing list how to use the patch and got no response.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have easily googled this. Go check out [hginit.com](http://hginit.com).

The UID is a commit hash for a specific revision of files.

`hg clone -u revision url_of_repo`

or if you've already cloned:

`hg update --clean revision`  # --clean will throw away any changes to files

`hg import patch`

Comment: I did, but apparently I didn't know the right words to search for. I still get an "unknown revision" error. I suppose I got the wrong UID; thanks anyway.

Comment: search whether the revision exists at all: `hg log -r UID`